# How to check if an object is an array of a certain type

Tags: java, reflection, field

I have an object `Field field`.

I'd like to check if `field` is either an object of type `Foo` or an array: `Foo[]`.

Psuedo code:

```
if field.getType() is Foo || field.getType is Foo[]
```

Is this possible?

I've tried

```
if (field.getType().isArray())
    // do something
```

But this would only allow me to check if `field` is an array.

Doing this, on the contrary, will only check if it's an object of `Foo`

```
if (Foo.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
     // do something
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: " I have an object Field field " ?? Your object is of type Field. Y are you checking if its Foo or Foo[]

Comment: I edited my answer (it's now a new one :-))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is some code I used once to handle arrays of all primitive types in Java. As they do not extend the Object class, an instanceof check for Object[] is insufficent.

```
/* Check if the given object is an array. */
if (object.getClass().isArray()) {

    Class<?> componentType;
    componentType = object.getClass().getComponentType();

    if (componentType.isPrimitive()) {

        if (boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            for (boolean anElement : (boolean[]) object) {
                /* ... */
            }
        }

        else if (byte.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        else if (char.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        else if (double.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        else if (float.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        else if (int.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        else if (long.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        else if (short.class.isAssignableFrom(componentType)) {
            /* ... */
        }

        /* No else. No other primitive types exist. */
    }

    else {
        /* Do something with Object[] here. */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple compare should work

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Main {

String[] myStringArray;
String[] myStringArray2;

Object[] myObjectArray;

String str;


public static void main(String... args) {
        Field[] flds = Main.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : flds) {
            Class<?> c = f.getType();

            if (c == String[].class) {
                System.out.println("field" + f.getName() + " is String[]");
            } 
            if (c == String.class) {
                System.out.println("field" + f.getName() + " is String");
            }
            if (c == Object[].class) {
                System.out.println("field" + f.getName() + " is Object[]");
            } 
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Field you mention is a `java.lang.reflect.Field`, you can just do

```
field.getType().equals(Foo.class) || field.getType().equals(Foo[].class)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (field instanceof Object[])
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since array types are reified, you can just use

```
if ( field.getType() == Foo.class || field.getType() == Foo[].class ) {
}
```

Full example:

```
public class Scratchpad {
    String[] strings;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        if (Scratchpad.class.getDeclaredField("strings").getType() == String[].class) {
            System.out.println("They're Strings!");
        }

        if (Scratchpad.class.getDeclaredField("strings").getType() == Long[].class) {
            System.out.println("They're Longs!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not believe `Foo[].class` would even compile.

Comment: Evidently, I just tried `Foo[].class`, and that's not a valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo[] other = new Foo[1];
    other[0] = new Foo();

    System.out.println(isFooOrArrayOfFoo(foo));
    System.out.println(isFooOrArrayOfFoo(other[0]));
    System.out.println(isFooOrArrayOfFoo(new Object()));
}

private static boolean isFooOrArrayOfFoo(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Foo || o.getClass().equals(Foo.class) && o.getClass().isArray());
}
```